# Google Maps iOS didTapInfoWindowOfMarker not triggered when on top of other markers

Tags: ios, google-maps, infowindow, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm using the latest GoogleMaps-iOS v1.3 SDK.

I'm having trouble getting didTapInfoWindowOfMarker to trigger on info window taps, when there are multiple other markers just behind it. Instead, taps on the info window more often than not acts as if tapping a marker behind it instead (and opening a different info window).

In particular, on my map I have dozens and dozens of GMSMarkers very close to each other - close enough that any info window popup would cover multiple markers, even on the highest zoom levels.

Is there a way to force taps on the info window to be processed before taps on markers behind it?

Comment: Suggest we close this, since the problem was fixed 6 years ago and it's extremely unlikely it's going to help anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, I found this to be the best workaround:

https://github.com/ryanmaxwell/GoogleMapsCalloutView

Basically, return a zero-sized UIView in -(UIView*)mapView:markerInfoWindow: so there's no visible "google maps infowindow", and use the opportunity to create and add a custom UIView on top of the MapView at the same time. In mapView:didChangeCameraPosition, the UIView can be moved to track the marker as the map is moved around.

Edit: This also has the benefit that you can have real, interactive UIViews. (And the SMCalloutView looks much better than the default infoWindow in the googlemaps SDK, too)

Answer (score 3):

For the reference of future readers of this thread, this issue has been resolved in release 1.4.0 in July 2013. In the release notes, under the list of resolved issues, one can find:

**Info windows no longer allow taps to pass through them**

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the best solution, it seems a little backwards, especially with a lot of markers, but it should work.

In your map view delegate, set up your delegate for:

```
-(BOOL)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker 
{
    for (int x = 0; x < myMapView.markers.count; x++) 
    { 
        GMSMarker * tempMarker = myMapView.markers[x]; 
        tempMarker.tappable = NO; 
    }
    mapView.selectedMarker = marker; 
    return YES; 
}
```

then you'd have to set up another delegate method:

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate 
{
    for (int x = 0; x < myMapView.markers.count; x++) 
    { 
        GMSMarker * tempMarker = myMapView.markers[x]; 
        tempMarker.tappable = YES; 
    } 
}
```

I set this up just so if the user clicks offscreen, it will dismiss the info window and reengage the 'tappability' of the markers.  I know this isn't the best way, however, it seems like given your situation, you might not have a choice.

My suggestion would be that if you have an excessive amount of markers that are also offscreen, maybe you can set it to only disengage the onscreen markers via the visible region property (add this to your tapped marker delegate)

```
-(BOOL)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker
{
    GMSVisibleRegion myVisibleRegion = mapView.projection.visibleRegion;
    GMSCoordinateBounds * currentBounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc]initWithRegion:myVisibleRegion];
    for (int x = 0; x < myMapView.markers.count; x++) {
        if ([currentBounds containsCoordinate:marker.position]) {
            GMSMarker * tempMarker = myMapView.markers[x];
            tempMarker.tappable = NO;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Then just get the markers that are within those bounds.

If you do that, in your tap marker delegate, set it up as

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{ 
    for (int x = 0; x < myMapView.markers.count; x++) {
        GMSMarker * tempMarker = myMapView.markers[x];
        if (tempMarker.tappable == NO) {
            tempMarker.tappable = YES;
        }
    }
}
```

That way, it will only change the markers that aren't currently tappable.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So basically disable all markers, and dismiss infowindows and re-enable markers on tap outside the infowindow? Sounds like it could work (although "browsing" the markers would then require 2x the amount of taps). Good idea anyways, thanks! :)

Comment: this solution kinda work, BUT when you open a marker info-window and you want to open another marker info-window, 2 clicks are required, which is really annoying...

Comment: @taurus I know it's not the best, I'm just not sure about another way to make it work right now.

Comment: It's a good trick and I had +1 you answer; anyway, I think this should be considered a bug of the Google Maps iOS SDK. Do you know how to let them know?

Answer (score 1):

HERE IS A WAY TO ADJUST YOUR SELECTED MARKER POSITION ON THE MAP AS WELL AS DISABLE MARKERS BEHIND YOUR CUSTOM VIEW.  THESE ARE NOT ONE SIZE FITS ALL, AND YOU WILL NEED TO ADJUST FOR YOUR SPECIFICATIONS.  ANY ADDITIONS HIGHLY WELCOMED . . .

ENJOY!

Taurus . . . I can't tell you exactly how to do it for your situation; however, I can give you my code to look at:

First, I adjust my map so that the marker is positioned in a more ideal location than center . . .

(it's important to note, this requires a northern bearing, if you allow users to rotate the map, you'll have to adjust accordingly)

You can store the adjustment requirements in a variable and use the same ones as long as zoom remains unchanged

```
- (void) adjustDisplayForImage: (GMSMarker *) marker
{
    // GET AN OFFSET AMOUNT IN DEGREES IN ORDER TO PROPERLY PLACE THE MARKER ACCORDING TO ZOOM

    CGPoint topLeft = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
    CGPoint lowerLeft = CGPointMake(0, screenRect.size.height);

    CLLocationCoordinate2D topLeftCoordinate = [myMapView.projection coordinateForPoint:topLeft];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D lowerLeftCoordinate = [myMapView.projection coordinateForPoint:lowerLeft];

    CGFloat screenDistanceInDegreesLatitude = topLeftCoordinate.latitude - lowerLeftCoordinate.latitude;
    CGFloat adjustmentDistanceInDegreesLatitude = screenDistanceInDegreesLatitude / 2.8;
    // this is the amount that the new center needs to be offset in order to orient marker on screen

    // these are CLLocationDegrees variables, declared elsewhere
    adjustedLatitudeDegrees = marker.position.latitude + adjustmentDistanceInDegreesLatitude;

    adjustedLatitudeDegrees = marker.position.latitude + adjustmentDistanceInDegreesLatitude;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D newCenterCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(adjustedLatitudeDegrees, marker.position.longitude);

    myMapView.selectedMarker = marker;
    [myMapView animateToLocation:newCenterCoordinate];

    // I'm saving the current zoom so I don't have to get my adjustment distances again unless zoom changes
    lastZoom = myMapView.zoom;
}
```

Ok, now I have that information, let's remove markers behind our view . . .

```
- (void) disableMarkersBehindView
{
    // my marker window is 213 x 280

    int markerWindowHeight = 280;
    int markerWindowWidth = 213;
    int approximateMarkerHeight = 10;

    // I'm just guessing here for marker height, whatever your marker's height is, use that

    // because of my adjustment, the marker position is adjusted about down 35% from the middle

    CGFloat adjustedDistanceInCGPoints =  myMapView.frame.size.height * (1 / 2.7);

    // This is because the marker defaults to the middle of the screen
    CGFloat middleY = myMapView.frame.size.height / 2;
    CGFloat newMarkerPositionY = middleY + adjustedDistanceInCGPoints;

    CGFloat topOfMarkerWindowY = newMarkerPositionY - markerWindowHeight - approximateMarkerHeight;

    // now we need a NorthEast and a SouthWest coordinate

    // NORTHEAST

    CGFloat halfWidth = myMapView.frame.size.width / 2;
    CGFloat northEastX = halfWidth - (markerWindowWidth / 2);

    CGPoint northEastCGPoint = CGPointMake(northEastX, topOfMarkerWindowY);

    CLLocationCoordinate2D northEastCoordinate = [myMapView.projection coordinateForPoint:northEastCGPoint];

    // SOUTHWEST

    CGFloat southWestX = halfWidth + (markerWindowWidth / 2);
    CGPoint southWestCGPoint = CGPointMake(southWestX, newMarkerPositionY);

    CLLocationCoordinate2D southWestCoordinate = [myMapView.projection coordinateForPoint:southWestCGPoint];

    // Now, make a boundary

    GMSCoordinateBounds * myViewBounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc]initWithCoordinate: northEastCoordinate coordinate:southWestCoordinate];

    for (int x = 0 ; x < myMapView.markers.count ; x++) {

        GMSMarker * marker = myMapView.markers[x];
        if ([myViewBounds containsCoordinate:marker.position]) {
            marker.tappable = NO;
            // here maybe add the markers to a seperate array so you can quickly make them tappable again wherever you need to
        }
    }
}
```

This takes into account various zoom levels, if you are restricting zoom on your map, you could probably simplify it.

Remember to make your markers tappable again, that's why I suggested maybe saving them in a separate Array

And don't forget, the adjustment is based on a Northern bearing only, to disable rotating bearing, use

```
myMapView.settings.rotateGestures = NO;
```

If not, make sure to reorient your map to North first or do some MATH!

-- Hope this helps!

Comment: That's quite the brute force approach! :) Unfortunately, I think it will be problematic when you allow users to zoom, pan, rotate and even psuedo-3d-tilt the map.

Comment: @Faffaffaff It most definitely will be. Users can zoom freely without problem; however tilting and panning cause problems. I already mentioned that specifically above.  I do however agree its Not very elegant. I'm going to try the ryannaxwell approach above

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did. Set mapview.delegate = self

your .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate>

@end
```

viewDidLoad of .m file

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:40.124291
                                                                longitude:-104.765625
                                                                     zoom:2];
        mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
        mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
        self.view = mapView_;
        mapView_.delegate = self;
    }

#pragma mark - set current location
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{

}

#pragma mark - mapview events
-(BOOL) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker{
    NSLog(@"%@", marker.description);
//    show info window
    [mapView_ setSelectedMarker:marker];
    return YES;
}

-(void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker{
    NSLog(@"info window tapped");
}
```